# Sublime Text open project file in existing window

Tags: sublimetext3

Whenever I double click a sublime project file on my Windows 10 machine, it opens a new windowed instance of sublime text.

How can I have the double click project open in the existing sublime window, replacing any open project.

"open_files_in_new_window": false, does not have any affect on opening projects.

Comment: Would doing `Project->Switch Project` work well enough for you?

Comment: No. I do use that functionality. But sometimes I have a project file in windows explorer, and I just want to double click it.

Comment: AFAIK, you can only add files/folders to an existing window (making use of `subl -a <file_or_folder>` through CLI or in your file association settings)

Comment: **Type: Related solution**. I added my projects directory (e.g. `User\Projects`) to my project → I pressed `Ctrl+P` → I can select and open any project file in existing window. Maybe that will suit you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With the Sublime Text project file open as a project, on the main menus go to: `Project -> Edit Project` and the .sublime-project file is opened as a text file for editing. Seems to apply settings to the open project when the file is saved.